# HTML/CSS nav bar spacing issues with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Could not yet find this exact issue that I am having addressed, so it here goes:

I am trying to create a nav bar with a heading on the left-hand side, and some nav items on the right.  I also want the nav to be centered on the page, with a width of 960px.  I am trying to accomplish 2 additional things:

1.) The nav bar should be fixed to the top so that it does not disappear when you scroll.

2.) The spacing between the heading and the nav items should be the first to disappear when you minimize the screen.  Currently, the items do not flex at all.

I am able to get one of these two things accomplished at a time, but not both at the same time.  Any help would be most welcome, thank you.

```css
html {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.banner {
  background-color: aqua;
  opacity: .5;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: fixed;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 4rem;
  align-items: center;
  width: 960px;
}

.container .banner .header h1 {
  margin-left: 2.5rem;
}

.container .banner .header .nav ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 2.5rem;
}

.container .banner .header .nav ul a {
  color: black;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="banner">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>My Sweet Sweet Georgia</h1>
      <div class="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">doggy</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">puppy</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">toys</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide working code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `align-items: left` for your heading and `align-items: right` instead of using `margin`

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.container .header {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 4rem;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: aqua;
  opacity: .7;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.container .header .nav ul li {
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My Puppy</title>
  <link href="./resources/reset.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="./resources/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>My Sweet Sweet Georgia</h1>
      <div class="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">doggy</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">puppy</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">toys</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yeah, I gave that a shot too.  Unfortunately, it didn't work out for me.

Answer (score 0):

In your css file:

remove in .header

```
.header {
    width: 960px;
}
```

add in .banner

```
.banner {
    max-width: 960px;
    width: 100%;
}
```